# Compiling a library with MingW

Tags: c++, mingw, configure, msys

I am trying to compile a library using MingW, but when I `./configure` nothing really happens.

I read that I need to install MSYS, which I did, just to get a post install output saying:

```
D:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\msys\1.0\postinstall>..\bin\sh.exe pi.sh
      0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x71110000, BaseAddress 0x71110000, RegionSize 0x1000, State 0x10
00
D:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space
for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0

D:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\msys\1.0\postinstall>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

after which trying to run opens up a command prompt which closes immediately, before I get to see what it says.

Comment: `MSYS` / `cygwin` sounds strange. Could it be a problem of your Qt Builder configuration?

Comment: Yah, sounds like it's picking up an incompatible MSYS DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the same problem, the MSYS that came with "stock" MinGW worked, but the standalone I tried installing to work alongside the MinGW installed by Qt did not. Then I noticed `msys-1.0.dll` - allegedly the same version has different sizes, copied the one from the stock MinGW MSYS over to the standalone MSYS and it worked - I was able to configure MSYS to work with Qt's MinGW install.

Seems like the MSYS standalone installer comes with the wrong DLL.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you have Cygwin's "bin" directory in your PATH.

Comment: I don't have Cygwin at all, much less a path to it.